# Xamarin Forms, EF Core 5 and SQLite: Join table of Many-To-Many is not being cleared when deleting

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

The join table of a many-to-many relationship in my Xamarin.Forms application seems to not be cleared correctly when deleting one of the two entities.

I have these classes:

```
public class Input
{
    // One-to-many
    public ObservableCollection<InputResult> InputResults { get; set; }

    //...
    // Here are many more entities which shouldn't be relevant for this example
    //...
}

public class InputResult
{
    // One-to-many
    public string ParentInputId { get; set;}

    // Many-to-many
    public ObservableCollection<MyDropdown> MyDropdowns { get; set; }
}

public class MyDropdown
{
    // Many-to-many
    public ObservableCollection<InputResult> InputResults { get; set; }
}
```

I configured the relationships in my `DbContext` class like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Input>()
               .HasMany(b => b.InputResults)
               .WithOne()
               .HasForeignKey(b => b.ParentInputId)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<InputResult>()
                .HasMany(b => b.MyDropdowns)
                .WithMany(b => b.InputResults);
```

Let's say I have previously loaded an `Input` with its `InputResults`. Then I delete the `InputResults` in a helper class like that:

```
Context.RemoveRange(Input.InputResults);
```

The `InputResults` get deleted correctly. When I look into the SQLite database directly I still see all the entries in the join table of `InputResults` and MyDropdown. Why are there still entries? Yesterday one of our users got a unique constraint error after deleting some data and trying to insert the same data again.

I appreciate any help.

**Edit:**

To expand my comment on CSharp's answer:

I can't use `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)` when configuring the DbContext. It seems as EF Core did this correctly by itself though. The part of the join table in the `DatabaseContextModelSnapshot.cs` looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("InputResultMyDropdown", b =>
{
    b.HasOne("Inputs.MyDropdown", null)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("MyDropdownId")
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .IsRequired();

    b.HasOne("Inputs.InputResult", null)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("InputResultId")
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .IsRequired();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a cascade delete behavior in DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<InputResult>()
    .HasMany(b => b.MyDropdowns)
    .WithMany(b => b.InputResults)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Comment: I can't use OnDelete here. The compiler says there is no definition of it which accepts a parameter of the type CollectionCollectionBuilder<MyDropdown, InputResult>.

Comment: I edited my original question. Maybe you can see some mistakes there. Thanks a lot!